# How to disable set -e and set -o

Tags: bash, unix

So I have this at the start of a bash script file (-e and -o).
However, in some functions, I would like for it to not exit out. Example

```
set -e
set -o pipefail

function check_status {
    echo "Start Check"
    docker exec mservice bash -c "echo 'Hello' | grep 'fail'"
    echo "End check"
}

check_status
```

How can I prevent this from exiting out of the script - basically if I run this, it would printout "Start Check", but then exit because the next command returns a '1'.

I would like to be able to disable and enable the set -e/-o in multiple places or in different functions.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For all options, the opposite of `set -` is `set +` (note the plus sign).

So `set +e` will undo `set -e`, and `set +o pipefail` will undo `set -o pipefail`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also leave the settings alone, and do something as simple as:

```
docker exec mservice bash -c "echo 'Hello' | grep 'fail'" || true
```

...and in so doing force a successful run of that command list. There would be no programmatic way to detect the failure of the docker command in this case, but if the command emits some error message, the human observer may notice.

Or you can handle the error in your function

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail

function check_status {
    if docker exec mservice bash -c "echo 'Hello' | grep 'fail'"; then
        echo good
    else
        echo bad
    fi
}

status=$(check_status)

if [ "$status" = 'bad' ]; then
  echo "check_status failed, but still running, handling the error..."
fi
```

Saving as `testfail.sh` and running it for me causes failure, since my docker installation does not include anything named `mservice`:

```
$ ./testfail.sh 
Error response from daemon: No such container: mservice
check_status failed, but still running, handling the error...
$
```